# Revit 2022 - Unable to load in a tool

Tags: c#, revit-api

I've been developing an application for Revit 2019-2022. The app I've made works in all versions apart from 2022, theres no clear error message.

The API has changed with every different Revit version released, I've checked whats changed but I can't seem to find anything that has with what I'm using.

There are multiple applications being loaded in, but this is the only one that doesn't seem to work.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzYUV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following some of the standard steps for debugging such a problem. One easy and reliable approach is to implement a brand new minimal skeleton add-in for Revit 2022 following the `Hello World` instructions in the [Revit Developer Guide for the Revit 2022 API](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html). Ensure that it loads and executes as expected, then transfer your existing add-in functionality to it piece by small piece. If it breaks at some point, you will be able to isolate the problem. If it does not break, your problem is solved. Good luck!